# Source for tallis vs no tallis for kibbud at Shabbos Mincha

Tags: shabbat, synagogue, tallit-gadol, mincha-afternoon-prayer

At my shul, which davens Ashkenaz, the Rav of the shul instituted a rule that at Shabbos mincha, only the baal tefila and baal kriah wears a tallis. People getting a kibbud do not.
I have previously only seen this at Chasidish or Sefardic shuls.
I tried looking and could not find any of the sources for this custom either way. I'm assuming it is mentioned in the Shaarei Ephraim? Can anyone point me in the direction of the sources both for and for not wearing a tallis when receiving a kibbud at Shabbos mincha? Is there any basis for not doing this in an Ashkenaz shul?
Thank you.

Comment: Your Rav might be a good person to ask since it was his decision. Just be respectful with how you ask the question

Comment: I wouldn't call him my Rav. He is the Rav of the shul. He was pretty dismissive he more or less said this is the way it is.

Comment: I see. Not so helpful. I wonder why have anyone wear a tallis at mincha since the primary time is shachris anyways?

Comment: typically the person davening for the amud wears a tallis at mincha to kavod to the position of being shliach tzibbur and to show honor to the congregation. I'm not clear why but I've seen in some shuls the baal tefila wears a tallis at Shabbos and Yontif mincha but not on a weekday.